# What is the equivalent of webviewdidfinishload in OSX swift?

Tags: javascript, swift, macos

I am making an app that will run javascript command: `webView.mainFrameDocument.title` after the web page has fully loaded. However I don't know what webView.mainFrameDocument.title is on OSX. I am using Xcode 7 and WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?

```
webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: redirectURL)!))
```

Comment: no, i am talking about having a method run when the request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still asking, try this

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

Comment: This assumes the use of `WKWebView` (which is what everyone should be using now). But the OP was asking about the deprecated `WebView`.